# Axiom of Choice iff Every set has a choice function

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I'd like to know if my proof is correct or incorrect in the following.

Given definition of Axiom of Choice (AoC): The direct product of a family of non-empty sets indexed by a non-empty set is non-empty.

Show that the Axiom of Choice is equivalent to the statement that every set has a choice function.

(Choice Function => AoC):

Suppose every set has a choice function.

Let S be a set, and fix a natural number n.

Let $$
I = \{1,2,....,n\}
 $$
and let $\mathbf A$ be a family of non-empty subsets of S sets indexed over I.

$$
\mathbf A = \{A_1, A_2, ... , A_n\}
$$

The task is to show that the direct product over sets in $\mathbf{A}$ is non-empty. This will be shown if an element of this set can be produced.

Let
$$
D = A_1 \times A_2 \times ... \times A_n
$$

By supposition, this set has a choice function $f$ defined over non-empty subsets $X$ of $D$ with the following:

$f: X \to D$ such that $f(X)∈X$ for all subsets $X$.

So, $f(X) ∈ X$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(X) ∈ D$.

So, $D$ is non-empty.

(Show AoC => Choice Function):

Suppose the Axiom of Choice, let S be a set, and fix a natural number n.

Let
 $$
I = \{1,2,....,n\}
 $$
and let

$$
\mathbf{A} = \{A_1,A_2,....,A_n \}
 $$

be a family of non-empty subsets of S indexed over I.

Let
$$
D = A_1 \times A_2 \times ... \times A_n
$$

By the Axiom of choice, $D$ is non-empty.

Let $y ∈ D$ and define a function $f: D \to D$ by $f(x) = y$ for all elements $x ∈ D$.

(So, every element of D is mapped to this fixed element $y$.)

So, $f(x)∈D$ for all $x∈ D$.

In other words, $f$ defines a choice function on $D$.

So, assuming the Axiom of Choice implies that $S$ has a choice function defined on its non-empty subsets.

Comment: Your choice function -> AoC argument looks wrong to me.  'By supposition, this set has a choice function defined over non-empty subsets', but you haven't shown that there _are_ any non-empty subsets of D! That is, after all, the thing you're trying to prove.

Comment: Also, you index over 'finite' products $A_1\ldots A_n$, but that doesn't take AC; the non-emptyness of a _finite_ product can be proven in ZF. Choice is only relevant for infinite products.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The set-theoretic def'n of $\prod_{j\in J}A_j$ is the set of functions from $J$ into $\cup \{A_j:j\in J\}$ that satisfy $\forall j\in J\;(f(j)\in A_j). $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are working only with finite products, and this hold in general. In the Choice Function $\Rightarrow$ AoC direction you don't know if $D$ is nonempty, that is what you are trying to pare working only with finite products, and this hold in general. In the AoC $\Rightarrow$ Choce Function direction you need a choice function on $\mathcal{A},$ not in $D.$ Moreover, I think we need to clarify some definitions.

First one definition

**Definition:** Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a nonempty collection os sets. A surjective function $f$ from some set $J$ to $\mathcal{A}$ is called an *indexing function* for $\mathcal{A}.$ $J$ is called the *index set*. The collection $\mathcal{A},$ together with $f,$ is called an *indexed family of sets.*

I'll use your definition of axiom of choice.

**Axiom of choice:** For any indexed family $\{ A_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in J}$ of nonempty sets, with $J \neq 0,$ the cartesian product
$$ \prod_{\alpha \in J} A_\alpha$$
is not empty. Recall that the cartesian product is the set of all functions
$$ \mathbf{x}:J \to \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}A_\alpha$$
such that $\mathbf{x}(\alpha) \in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in J.$

Now,

**Existence of a choice function**: Given a collection $\mathcal{A}$ of nonempty sets, there exists a function
$$ c: \mathcal{A} \to \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{A}}A$$
such that $c(A)$ is an element of $A: c(A)\in A$ for each $A \in \mathcal{A}.$

**Axiom of choice $\Rightarrow$ Existence of choice function.**

We are assuming that for any indexed family $\{ A_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in J}$ of nonempty sets, with $J \neq 0,$ the cartesian product $ \prod_{\alpha \in J} A_\alpha$ is not empty. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of nonempty sets. We have to prove that there exists a function $ c: \mathcal{A} \to \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{A}}A$ such that $c(A) \in A$ for each $A \in \mathcal{A}.$ We first index $\mathcal{A}$: let $J=\mathcal{A}$ and $f:\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ given by $f(A)=A.$ Then $\{A\}_{A \in \mathcal{A}}$ is an indexed family of sets, so we can consider its cartesian product $\prod_{A \in \mathcal{A}}A.$ By hypothesis, this product is nonempty, so there exists a function
$$ \mathbf{x}: \mathcal{A} \to \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{A}}A$$
such that $\mathbf{x}(A) \in A$ for each $A \in \mathcal{A}.$ Then $c=\mathbf{x}$ is the function we were looking for.

**Existence of choice function $\Rightarrow$ Axiom of choice**

Now we are assuming that the existence of choice function, and let $\{A_\alpha \}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of nonempty sets, with $J \neq 0.$ This means that there is a nonempty collection of sets $\mathcal{A}$ and there is an indexing (i.e. surjective) function $f:J \to \mathcal{A}$ such that $f(\alpha)=A_\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$ for each $\alpha \in J.$ By the existence of choice function, there is a function $c:\mathcal{A} \to \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{A}}A$ such that $c(A) \in A$ for each $A \in \mathcal{A}.$ Thus
the function
$$ \mathbf{x}:= c \circ f : J \to \mathcal{A} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}A_\alpha$$
satisfies $\mathbf{x}(\alpha)=c(f(\alpha))=c(A_\alpha) \in A_\alpha$ for each $\alpha \in J,$ so the product $\prod_{\alpha \in J}A_\alpha$ is nonempty.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback; I appreciate it! 

Btw, this is just for my own interest; not for a class or anything...

Comment: A member of $P=\prod_{a\in A}A_a$ is a choice-function for $\{A_a:a\in A\}$ by the def'n of $P$ and the def'n of a choice-function.  So the proposition is essentially a tautology.

Comment: Your answer is clear, full of relevant definitions, and concise!

Comment: It is an equivalent version of the Axiom Choice you are using but with the functions $x$. That equivalence can be proved with induction over $J$.